# r.js not minifying jquery mobile

Tags: jquery-mobile, requirejs

I have a project in which I'm using RequireJS and jquery-mobile.  I've tried to run r.js to compile the full project, but it seems jquery-mobile is being omitted from the compile process.

I realize that CDN is an option for most projects, this one is internal and may not have network connectivity so it's not really an option here.

This is my main config file:

```
require.config({
  baseUrl: "js",
  paths: {
    "backbone": "vendor/backbone-amd/backbone",
    "jquery": "vendor/jquery/jquery",
    "jquery-mobile": "vendor/jquery-mobile-compiled/jquery-mobile",
    "waypoints": "vendor/jquery-waypoints/waypoints",
    "modernizr": "vendor/modernizr/modernizr",
    "requirejs": "vendor/requirejs/require",
    "underscore": "vendor/underscore-amd/underscore",
    "text": "vendor/requirejs-text/text",
    "handlebars": "vendor/handlebars.js/handlebars"
  },
  shim: {
    "handlebars": {
      exports: "Handlebars"
    },
    "modernizr": {
      exports: "Modernizr"
    }
  }
});


// Includes File Dependencies
require([ "jquery", "backbone", "router/mobileRouter", "modernizr" ], function ($, Backbone, MobileRouter, Modernizr) {

  $(document).on("mobileinit",
    // Set up the "mobileinit" handler before requiring jQuery Mobile's module
    function () {
      // Prevents all anchor click handling including the addition of active button state and alternate link bluring.
      $.mobile.linkBindingEnabled = false;

      // Disabling this will prevent jQuery Mobile from handling hash changes
      $.mobile.hashListeningEnabled = false;
    }
  );

  if(Modernizr.touch) {
    $(document).on("click", function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
    });
  }

  require([ "jquery-mobile" ], function () {
    // Instantiates a new Backbone.js Mobile Router
    this.router = new MobileRouter();
  });
});
```

This is basically an exact copy of the example that comes with jquery-mobile.  But as you can see I have "jquery-mobile" in the paths and it's within a nested require near the bottom.

My app.build.js looks like this:

```
({
  "appDir": "../",
  "baseUrl":"js",
  "dir":"../../dist",
  "mainConfigFile": "../js/main.js",
  "modules": [
    {
      "name": "main"
    }
  ],
  "skipDirOptimize": true,
  "optimizeCss": "standard"
})
```

After I run the following command:

```
r.js -o app/build/app.build.js
```

I see that everything is mashed into the main.js EXCEPT jquery-mobile.js.  When I hit the site that's been compiled, I find the only JS files that are being pulled are: requirejs.js, main.js, and jquery-mobile.js.

Why isn't jquery-mobile being minified like the rest of the scripts?

Comment: Interesting issue. Can you in your paths point to already minified version?

Comment: I can of course, but it doesn't combine with the the others in the main.js (when attempting to minimize the number of requests to the server).